# What secrets of the Bible that you know and others don't unless you tell them?

Tags: bible

I think the Bible is a dossier on ending child scarifice in all its forms forever. What's your secret?

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site. Please make sure you read the [tour] if you haven't yet. Unfortunately this kind of question isn't what we do here, this is a discussion starter, but this site only allows finite questions that are in principle objectively answerable.

Comment: After 1700 years of being studied it is safe to assume that there are no 'secrets' in the Bible that only one person knows

Comment: I see that I got 11 just below my name. What does that mean? Much appreciated.

Comment: 11 (now 9) is the number of reputation points you have on the site. See https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: Ok thanks. Keep firing those gears DJ. You're the man.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell if this question is trying to be funny or what. But if you are looking for a legit answer here it is. There are no "secrets" about the Bible. There are things that you may not find in the Bible like other history information. The Bible isn't meant to be a secret nor is it meant to be about ending child sacrifice. I have no idea where you got that from.

The Bible tells us about the Lord God, history, God's plan, and much more. The Bible also acts as an authoritative source. Besides the 4 gospels, Acts, and the book of Revelation, pretty much every other book in the New Testament is authoritative. The Bible is also meant to help us go through struggles through faith.

I hope everything I have said makes sense. If I have said anything wrong, I hope that my peers can help explain it better.